# Scala Seq[Type] Error when Pattern Matching

Tags: scala

I have a Seq as:

```
def myMethod(mySeq: Seq[SomeType]) = mySeq match {
  case Nil => // do someting
  case _   => // do something else (error happens here)
}
```

When I run this code, I get the following error:

```
a type was inferred to be `Any`; this may indicate a programming error
```

I have never seen this error thus far. I'm on Scala 2.11. I'm clueless as to what this error is? Any clues?

Edit: Here is the actual method that I have under question:

```
  def publishMessages(mySeq: Seq[MyData]): Future[Continue] = Future {

    if (mySeq.nonEmpty) {
      logger.info(s"sending a total of ${mySeq.length} for " +
        s"metric ${mySeq.head.metric} messages to kafka topic ${producerConfig.topic}")

      val jsonMessage = Json.stringify(Json.toJson(mySeq))
      val recordMetaDataF = Future {
        scala.concurrent.blocking {
          val recordMetaDataJavaFut = producer.send(
            new ProducerRecord[String, String](producerConfig.topic, jsonMessage)
          )
          // if we don't make it to Kafka within 3 seconds, we timeout
          recordMetaDataJavaFut.get(3, TimeUnit.SECONDS)
        }
      }

      recordMetaDataF.recover {
        case NonFatal(ex) =>
          logger.error("Exception while persisting data-points to kafka", ex)
      }
      Continue
    }
    else {
      logger.debug(s"skip persisting to kafka topic ${producerConfig.topic} as no " +
        " data-points were given to persist")
      Continue
    }
  }
```

Here is the warning that I see when I compile:

```
[warn] Scala version was updated by one of library dependencies:
[warn]  * org.scala-lang:scala-library:(2.11.1, 2.11.7, 2.11.2, 2.11.6, 2.11.5, 2.11.0) -> 2.11.8
[warn] To force scalaVersion, add the following:
[warn]  ivyScala := ivyScala.value map { _.copy(overrideScalaVersion = true) }
[warn] Run 'evicted' to see detailed eviction warnings
```

I still get this error:

```
a type was inferred to be `Any`; this may indicate a programming error
```

Comment: What is the something else you are trying to do?

Comment: Why should that be important? Both the paths return a proper and the same type. IntelliJ does not complain on this method!

Comment: Because the code you posted doesn't need to infer anything with blank comments, so it produces no error.

Comment: Please take a look now at my post! You will be bemused!

Comment: What line gives the error? Your first abstracted code uses match, your "real" code doesn't so it's kind of difficult to guess what's really happening

Comment: I originally did not want to post the actual code, so I just made up a sample that mimics what I do. It does not matter, if I use case block or if condition. The question still remains as to why my actual code fails compilation?

Comment: I don't suppose you'd like to actually answer the question and say what line gives the error?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This has to do with what "do something" means in your app:

```
scala> def myMethod(mySeq: Seq[String]) = mySeq match {
 |       case Nil => ""
 |       case _   => 12
 |     }
myMethod: (mySeq: Seq[String])Any

scala> def myMethod(mySeq: Seq[String]) = mySeq match {
 |       case Nil => ""
 |       case _   => "123"
 |     }
myMethod: (mySeq: Seq[String])String
```

As you can see in the first case the type don't align and the return type inferred by the compiler is `Any`, in the second they are both strings and the returned type is `String`, you should explicitly annotate the return type and that probably won't compile (unless it's `Any`).

Comment: Your edit has nothing wrong, I suspect you are just looking at the wrong line or the code you posted is incomplete, if this was not the case it would not compile at all because the type wouldn't match instead of giving you a warning (the `Any` message is a warning not an error, unless you set your flags in a certain way).